# How to format my code example with vue-styleguidist?

Tags: react-styleguidist, vue-styleguidist

I want to use vue-styleguidist to document my components. Decided to start with a spinner.
A preview of the component is displayed properly but the code example is not formatted as I expected (check https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/basic/#button for the reference).

How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a config flag that will remove all styling from the editor, if case you plan on using your own prismjs theme:

[jssThemedEditor](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/Configuration.html#jssthemededitor)

If it is set to false, you will get exactly this result.

Otherwise, open the browsers console, there is always some information about what went wrong.

I hope this helps, keep us posted.